# How to access data stored in Hash

Tags: perl, json

I have this code:

```
$coder = JSON::XS->new->utf8->pretty->allow_nonref;
%perl = $coder->decode ($json);
```

When I write `print %perl` variable it says HASH(0x9e04db0). How can I access data in this HASH?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return value of `decode` isn't a hash and you shouldn't be assigning it to a `%hash` -- when you do, you destroy its value. It's a hash *reference* and should be assigned to a scalar. Read [perlreftut](http://p3rl.org/perlreftut).

Comment: OK, I figured out that print keys %{$perl} gets me key from Hash, but print values %{$perl} gets me another Hash reference. So I stored this reference in new scalar variable, but when I try to access data in this Hash, it gives me nothing.

$json = '{"glossary": {"title": "example glossary","GlossDiv": {"title": "S"}}}';

$coder = JSON::XS->new->utf8->pretty->allow_nonref;
$perl = $coder->decode ($json);
print keys %{$perl},"\n"; #give me glossary
print values %{$perl},"\n"; #give me HASH(address)
my $val = values %{$perl}; # store address
print keys %{$val}; ##give nothing -- title expected

Answer (score 13):

As the `decode` method actually returns a *reference* to hash, the proper way to assign would be:

```
%perl = %{ $coder->decode ($json) };
```

That said, to get the data from the hash, you can use the [each](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html) builtin or loop over its keys and retrieve the values by subscripting.

```
while (my ($key, $value) = each %perl) {
    print "$key = $value\n";
}

for my $key (keys %perl) {
    print "$key = $perl{$key}\n";
}
```

Answer (score 7):

JSON::XS->decode returns a reference to an array or a hash. To do what you are trying to do you would have to do this:

```
$coder = JSON::XS->new->utf8->pretty->allow_nonref;
$perl = $coder->decode ($json);

print %{$perl};
```

In other words, you'll have to dereference the hash when using it.

Answer (score -3):

Lots of ways, you can use a `foreach loop`

```
foreach my $key (%perl)
{
  print "$key is $perl{$key}\n";
}
```

or a `while loop`

```
while (my ($key, $value) = each %perl)
{
  print "$key is $perl{$key}\n";
}
```

Answer (score -3):

> 

You need to specify the particular key of hash, Then only you will be able to access the data from the hash .

For example if %perl hash has key called 'file' ;

You suppose to access like below

print $perl{'file'}  ; # it would print the file key value of the %perl hash

> 