# Need example of Perl JSON usage

Tags: json, perl

how do I parse a JSON string in Perl?

Note: I am a C++/Java/C# software engineer, not a Perl-wielding scripter.

I have fully read the [JSON.pm](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.53/lib/JSON.pm) "documentation" to find a working example, but those docs turned out to be complete and utter garbage".

I also read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270225/parsing-json-with-perl), but no one seems to know how to get the JSON key, value pairs out of the decoded perl variable.

Here is my script. Can someone help?

```
use JSON;

my $json_string = '{"foo": "bar"}';
my $decoded_json = decode_json($json_text);
print $decoded_json["foo"];

std::map<string, string> mymap = convert_to_cplusplus(decoded_json); # doesn't work
my asfjsa;fjsa;fwe # doesn't work
```

I got frustrated near the end.

Comment: To the downvoter: There's no need to downvote this question...the OP was just a little frustrated, and in this instance, I can actually understand. The documentation was written with a seasoned Perl programmer in mind, so it's rather daunting if you're not such.

Comment: @Chris: Maybe this has to do with the general tone. C++ is magic to me but that wouldn't warrant me call the documentation of a C++ lib garbage when it is written for a seasoned C++ programmer. (I didn't downvote though.)

Comment: humph. What's with the implication that Perl programmers can't be software engineers? I didn't downvote either, but I'm not very tempted to help either.

Comment: I do not think you have to be a seasoned Perl programmer to understand the docs. As in other documentation it is assumed that you understand the Perl datastructures. That is one of the minimum requirements no matter what language you write in.

Comment: -1 for the tone. Change the question into an emotionally neutral wording and substantiate your opinion why something is garbage.

Comment: Anyone who's too inexperienced to understand that you can engineer proper software in ANY language you're good at, and that it's about the developer, is clearly not a "software engineer". Coder, may be. Anyone too lazy to do ELEMENTARY google check (a full example - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354792/how-to-access-data-stored-in-hash - is a 3rd hit on searching `decode_json perl` on Google;  an even better tutorial is on 1st page of Google results - http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=651544) doesn't know how to learn.

Comment: i do understand the frustration part ... just wrestling with the somewhat cryptic perldocs myself

Answer (score 13):

You need to use `$decoded_json->{"foo"}`---note the curly brackets, not the square ones. Also note the arrow `->`---`decode_json` returns a reference.

I will readily admit that the documentation in this case is no help for someone who doesn't already know Perl, for example, to the level of knowing what `$perl_hash_or_arrayref` means. (A seasoned Perl programmer knows instantly it means you have to use `->`.)

Comment: You beat me to it. I also wanted to post a link to the perlref page: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html

Comment: @Igor: +1 Neat idea, though I think perlreftut might be a better idea. I think perlref will go over the poor OP's head. :-(

Comment: @Chris - it doesn't take a **seasoned** programmer to understand how to dereference a hash. Just a mildly competent one